# Cannot sum values downloaded into array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, unrecognized-selector

I am working on a project where I download a few values (stored as float in my database) into my array and sum them. I can NSLog the numbers but Unfortunately I am having the hardest time to sum those values in my array.

Adding some code

**DETAILS.H**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Details: NSObject
@property (nonatomic,  strong)NSNumber  *min;
//@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *min;
@end
```

**just the part of the code where I put the values in the array**

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];


    tempDetails *downloadTemps = [[tempDetails alloc] init];
    downloadTemps.min = jsonElement[@"min"];
    // Add this question to the locations array
    [_locations addObject:downloadTemps];
}
```

**View controller code**

```
for (Details *sav in _importArray )
{

    NSLog(@"High :- %@ ", sav.min); //THIS LIST ALL MY VALUES CORRECTLY
}

NSMutableArray *newArray = [_importArray mutableCopy];

int totalSum = 0;


for(int i=0; i<[newArray count];i++)
{
    totalSum = totalSum + [[newArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
}

NSLog(@"Total:%d",totalSum);
```

In the view controller I get the error
[Details intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ,
I am assuming I am getting this error because min is not declared right, But I am unsure how to do it other wise. Any help offered would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the selector `intValue`, but you should be asking for the selector `min`.

```
totalSum = totalSum + [[[newArray objectAtIndex:i] min] intValue];
```

You were pretty close in the first block you posted:

```
for (Details *sav in _importArray )
{
  NSLog(@"High :- %@ ", sav.min); //THIS LIST ALL MY VALUES CORRECTLY
}
```

Then:

```
int totalSum = 0;
for (Details *sav in _importArray )
{
  totalSum += [sav.min intValue];
}
```

Incidentally, why are you asking for the `intValue` of something that you initially wrote was a float?